# Aptana's appearance in Linux Mint

Tags: eclipse, themes, aptana, linux-mint

I'm running Linux Mint 15, Aptana 3.5. The interface in Aptana is looking particularly ugly, in my opinion, and I'm wondering if I have a setting wrong somewhere. I can edit the editor colors just fine, and those are good enough, but all of the theme choices , in General > Appearance > Theme seem a little confused. The screenshot linked to below shows the GTK theme. Note in particular the buttons in the Project Explorer and the separators in the toolbar buttons at the top.

Is this how it is supposed to look? Does it look like there might be some theme conflict among Mint, GTK, Aptana, and/or something else? Is there a place I can get alternative themes which look better? (I looked, but didn't find anything.)

I'd rather not go through editing the theme myself. I did find /opt/Aptana_Studio_3/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.1.v20130911-1000/css/e4_default_gtk.css, which appears to be the file I would edit if I wanted to undertake such a task. I shrunk the font in the tabs by editing that file, but I think it would be a slow process to figure out how to fix everything else in there.

Screen-shot [is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG2ok.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be an issue with version 3.5 (in fact has been removed), try to install version 3.4.2 instead

Comment: Works like a charm. For anyone else downgrading, I simply emptied the /opt/Aptana_Studio_3 folder, and dumped everything from the download in there. Working so far!